# Using gtags for gtk headers and my own project

Tags: tags, ctags, gnu-global

I have a gtk project and I want to use gtags for my project. I also would like to use gtags for the external libraries, in my case gtk. I tried:

```
find /usr/include/gtk-2.0 -name "*.h" > gtk_headers
gtags -f gtk_headers
```

Unfortunately, I get a segmentation fault here (using Ubuntu 12.04)

Any ideas how to get this work? (I am also happy with a solution with ctags or etags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$ (cd /usr/include/gtk-2.0; gtags)          # make tag in the library project
$ gtags                                     # make tag in your project
$ GTAGSLIBPATH=/usr/include/gtk-2.0; export GTAGSLIBPATH
$ global -x xxx
```

If 'xxx' exists in your project, global show it.
Otherwise, if 'xxx' exists in the library projects,
global show it.

To show both of them, please try this:

```
$ GTAGSTHROUGH=; export GTAGSTHROUGH
```

If you have many libraries then please specify them like PATH environment
variable.

```
$ GTAGSLIBPATH=/usr/src/lib:/usr/include/gtk-2.0; export GTAGSLIBPATH
```

Good luck!